# Android Heart beat recording apps

Tags: java, android

I am doing a android app which to analyze our heart beat rate by recording sound. While the apps recorded the user heart beat sound in audio file, but i have no idea how to do the algorithm to analyze the heart rate, can i do it in FFT??

Answer (score 2):

What exactly does the audio file contain? Did you record the heart beat by holding the smartphone on your heart?

You should implement a very good noise reduction and then try to get the main beat as the repeating loudest peak point in your recording.

FFT could give you the frequency of the signal with most energy (loudest) but counting peaks should also bring you to the same solution.

But before you start implementing anything. Listen to your recording and ask yourself, if you can hear the heartbeats. Your ears are one of the best noise reduction systems in the world. If you cant hear it, neither FFT nor any other algorithm will do it.